# How to use @MENTIONS IN textbox.IO plugin

Tags: wysiwyg, rich-text-editor, textboxio

[image]

I need to know whether this `@Mentions` option is there in the TextBox.io Plugin

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently have an @mentions feature in Textbox.io but it is something we're looking into for a future release.

Comment: We have @mentions now, but only in IBM Connections. If you'd like to know about when the feature may be available to all customers, please contact our support team.

Alternatively, it's available in TinyMCE today:
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/mentions/